# how can i convert this code from hover to either click or toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the script works fine with hover but need it to be either a toggle or a click function if anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this.
it collects data from different php files depending on the button that is hoverd over thats fine but when working on the page it pops up all the time kind of annoying

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".container").hide();
                $(['btn1', 'btn2', 'btn3']).each(function(){
                    var btn = this;
                    var con = $("#"+btn).children('.container');
                        $("#"+btn).hover(
                        function(){
                            $(".hover").mouseout();
                            $(this).addClass('hover');
                            var cache = $(con).children('p');
                    //check to see if content was loaded previously
                            if(cache.size()){
                                con.show();
                            }else{
                                    $(con).show();
                                    $(con).html('<img src="imgs/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
                                    $.ajax({
                                    url: 'data/'+btn+'.php',
                                    type: 'get',
                                    success: function(data){
                                    $(con).html(data);
                                    }
                                    });
                            }
                        },
                    //mouseout
                            function(){
                                if($.browser.msie){
                                $(con).hide();
                                }else{
                                $(con).fadeOut(250);
                                }
                                $(this).removeClass('hover');
                            }
                        );
                });
        });
    </script>






<div id="btn1" class="wrapper">
    <div class="button">
        <p><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="btn2" class="wrapper">
    <div class="button">
        <p><i  class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML.

Comment: Html below the code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i figured out how to do this and also make the coding less.
so what it does is you create the dropdown button with the btn1 id
and the next button with id of btn2.
the parsing php files called btn1.php you code what you need to display the data in the content div of the buttons

Aaaargh sorry seems like only the first button works shows the conent div and closes when clicked but subsequent new buttons show the content div Ajax requests are all fine 
but dont close when clicked again

```
    <script>
$(".wrapper").click( function()
           {
            var btn =  $(this).attr('id');
            var conte = $('.content').css('display');
            var con = $(this).children('.content');
            if (conte == 'block') {
            $(con).css('display','none');
            } else if (conte == 'none') {
    $(con).css('display','block');
    $(con).html('<img src="imgs/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
            $.ajax({
            url: 'configuration/'+btn+'.php',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data){
            $(con).html(data);
            }
        });
} 

});                 
    </script>
```